# Why when I unwrap my model does the field for the Torso come out so strange?

Tags: uv

I have been trying for the last 2 hours, fiddling with where I have placed my seams and either the torso or the legs end up like this. If someone could please tell me what it is I am doing wrong.

I would like to note this is one of my first proper modeling projects with Blender and one of the first times I've used the unwrapping tool so I am unfamiliar with it.

Thanks for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZxHg.png)

Comment: Check that there is a complete seam, around the neck, around the top of each arm, around the top of each leg. and at least one vertical seam running the complete length of the torso. In Face select mode, hover your mouse over the torso and press the L key. If your torso is completed isolated from the rest of the model with seams then only the torso will be selected. Usually for the torso you will have two seams, at the sides, running vertical, One under each arm down to the top of the legs.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are unwrapping the mesh wrong. You have it unwrapped in a sort of round ball shape on the UV map. If you unwrap it with cylinder projection, cube projection, or even just select one side of the chest and unwrap it that way, it will be more square-like/flat. That would work a bit better and you would not have stretched textures.